# Transforming Percent Change: Lognormal Distribution?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, data-transformation, lognormal-distribution

I am dealing with a dependent variable relating to the price of an asset and the percent change in the price of that asset. The problem with this type of analysis, like when stocks are the unit of analysis, is that it follows what looks like a log-normal distribution nut has an interval of [-1, +inf).

I have never dealt with transforming this type of DV for an OLS analysis. Everything I find in terms of literature is about stocks and why they follow a log-normal and not how to deal with it for any type of linear regression. I would also be open to another type of analysis if that is more 'normal' (no pun intended) and better.

An example: If there is an asset X that is worth 10 when it is bought (t = 0) and tomorrow (t = 1) it is valued at 0.01 then this is approximately a 100% decrease in price, and it can basically go no lower. However, if instead it increased to a worth of 1,000 (at t = 1) this is a 9900% increase.

Because my data fits a pattern like an asset I have a long right-tail and a distribution that looks log-normal. I was wondering how to deal with it.

Comment: "A lognormal distribution with an interval of [-1, +inf]" is strange. You should be taking the logarithms of *ratios* of prices, not differences, with resulting values in the range $(-\infty, \infty)$.  The ratios are easily recovered from the percent changes; a percent change of $i$ means the new price is $1+i/100$ times the old, so the variable to consider using is $\log(1+i/100)$. For small percents (positive or negative) this is close to $i/100$, so it's easy to interpret.

Comment: I don't understand the original problem.  How can the variable be log normal distributed if it has negative values?  Log normal is defined as if you take the logarithm of the original variable you get something that is normally distributed and the logarithm of -1 is undefined; log normal distributed RVs need to have positive values. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution.

Comment: @PeterEllis That is correct, I meant it looks like a log-normal shape wise BUT it includes negative values.

Comment: @whuber The confusion is the shape. If you take stock prices for example. If price at t = 0 is 10 and it drops to 0.01 at t = 1 then that is a ~ -100% change. However, if at t = 1 the price went to 1,000 that is now ~9900% change. Since I am dealing with assets that cannot get below $0 I have a distribution that looks log-normal expect for the fact that it takes on negative values. I wanted to transform the data into some normal fashion to analyze it with a linear regression, but I am open to other ideas.

Comment: How does it look if you take up @whuber's idea and instead of having change, use ratios - so your two examples become 0.01/10 =0.001 and 1000/10 = 100?  It doesn't sound likely to me that your change data really is a shifted log normal (which is what you are describing by saying it has the shape but not the position), although if it was you can transform it to normal by adding a constant and then taking a logarithm.

Comment: Look at the definition of the percentage change. Try taking logs of the series the percentage changes were computed from.